# append file nth lines before last line

Tags: bash

I searched for a good while but the closest I get to finding is appending to the last line.

One example I found was appending to the last line

`sed '$ e cat word.txt' test.txt`

The closest I got is using the `x` command with `sed` to get to the second to last line.

`sed 'x;$ e cat word.txt' test.txt`

However, I'd like to know how to append from the 3rd, 4th line, etc of the last line.

For example

**word.txt**

```
lorem ipsum...
```

**test.txt**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

appending the `word.txt` to the 4th to last line of `test.txt`

```
1
2
3
4
lorem ipsum...
5
6
7
```

The only examples I find are to append nth from the beginning of the line but not nth from the last last line.

Comment: Please post some test data and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Use `head` and `tail`:

```
{
    head -n-3 text.txt
    cat word.txt
    tail -n3 text.txt
} > newfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

In GNU awk (`ARGIND` variable):

```
$ awk -v nth=4 '
    ARGIND==1 { s=s (s==""?"":ORS) $0; next } 
    ARGIND==2 { nr=NR; next } 
    ARGIND==3 && FNR==(nr-nth) { print s } 
    1' word test test
1
2
3
lorem ipsum...
4
5
6
7
```

It reads `test` twice, calculates the record count on the first go.

Answer (score 0):

With awk you don't need to reverse the file prior to processing it:

```
awk -v last=3 -v toadd="$(<word.txt)" '
     NR > last { print a[(NR-1) % last] }
     { a[(NR-1) % last] = $0 }
     END{ 
         print toadd
         for(i=NR-last; i<NR; i++)
             print a[i % last]
     }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`, you can save all the lines and then print them in the `END` block as

```
{ lines[NR] = $0 }
END{ for (i = 1; i <= NR; i++) {
    if (NR-n + 1 == i)
        print word;
    print lines[i]
    }
}
```

**Example**

```
$ awk -vn=3 -vword="$(cat word)" -f prog.awk file
1
2
3
4
lorem ipsum..
5
6
7
```

Comment: The output record order is random. If you changed the `for` to `for(i=1;i<=nr;i++)` it would work. And I'm not sure `NR` is defined in `END` block.

Comment: @JamesBrown I am not sure why it was random. Anyways I have corrected it so that we don't have any surprises. The `NR` is available in the `END` block.